# Select the count records in Group by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I have a `wsm_Ref_Buildings` table which has `buildingid`, `city` columns. I want to see all the `buildingid` present in all the state. For eg: Hastings (`city`) has 18 buildings (`count`), I want to have all the 18 `buildingid` in the result.

Query

```
select count(BuildingId), city 
from wsm_Ref_Buildings 
group by City
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the total count as well as the Building name in a single Query?

Comment: yes @JayasuryaSatheesh correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to concatenate building id values and display with the city and building count,
Please check

```
select
    w.city,
    count(*) as cnt,
    stuff(
        (
            select ',' + convert(varchar(10),b.buildingid)
            from wsm_Ref_Buildings b
            where b.city = w.city
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) as list
from wsm_Ref_Buildings w
group by w.city
```

This is [string concatenation in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-concatenation-function-to-sql-concatenate-strings.aspx) for versions prior SQL Server 2017

If you have SQL Server 2017, you can use [string_agg string aggregation function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) as follows

```
select
  city,
  count(*) as cnt,
  string_agg( convert(varchar(10), buildingid) , ',' ) within group (order by buildingid) as list
from wsm_Ref_Buildings
group by city
```

Both queries will create following output with my sample data

[image]

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT 
    City,
    BuildID,
    BuildCnt = COUNT(BuildingId) OVER(PARTITION BY City) from wsm_Ref_Buildings
```

Demo

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    City VARCHAR(5),
    BuildID INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('ABC',1),('ABC',2),('ABC',3),('XYZ',1),('XYZ',4),('HIJ',6)

SELECT
    City,
    BuildID,
    BuildCnt = COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY City)
    FROM @T
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
City,BuildID,
(select COUNT(WS.BuildingId) from  wsm_Ref_Buildings AS WS 
WHERE  WS1.City=WS.City) as  BuildCnt  
from wsm_Ref_Buildings AS WS1
```